# Pass a SkillCoolDown value to the method as a unique parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, parameters

I have a Skill base class and 2 separate Skill classes that inherit from the Class Skill. Each skill has its own `SkillCoolDown` value. I set the `CoolDownManager` Class that is visualising the cooldowns for the skills, but I don't understand how to set the `SkillCoolDown` value to the manager which is different for each skill. Would appreciate the help.

```cs
public class Skill
{
    private string skillName;
    private int skillDamage;
    private string skillDescription;
    private int skillCoolDown;

    public string SkillName {get;set;}
    public int SkillDamage {get;set;}
    public string SkillDescription {get;set;}
    public int SkillCoolDown {get;set;}
    public Skill () {}
}
```

```cs
public class CoolDownManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Skill skill;
    private Stopwatch cooldown;
    private Button button;
    private Image fillImage;
    private int skillCoolDown;


    public void OnSkillUse(Button btn) {

        skill = new Skill();  // HERE THE VALUE SkillCoolDown SHOULD BE IMPLEMENTED AND I WANT SOMEHOW TO SHOW WHICH SKILL HAS BEEN USED.

        button = btn.GetComponent<Button>();
        fillImage = btn.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
        btn.interactable = false;
        fillImage.fillAmount = 1;
        cooldown = new Stopwatch();
        cooldown.Start();
        StartCoroutine(CoolDownAnimation());
    }


    private IEnumerator CoolDownAnimation() {
        while(cooldown.IsRunning && cooldown.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < skill.SkillCoolDown) {
            fillImage.fillAmount = ((float)cooldown.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / skill.SkillCoolDown);
            yield return null; 
        }

        fillImage.fillAmount = 0;
        button.interactable = true;
        cooldown.Stop();
        cooldown.Reset();
    }
}
```

And here is example of the Skill class from where the value `SkillCoolDown` should be passed.

```cs
public class BasicAttack : Skill
{
    public BasicAttack() 
    {
        SkillCoolDown = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Skill` could be passed to the `CooldownManager` via constructor injection:

```
public class CoolDownManager : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
   public Skill skill;
   // other properties

   public CoolDownManager(Skill skillParam)
   {
      skill = skillParam;
   }

   // do whatever you want with skill
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect problem to solve using [scriptable objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html).

The following class inherits from `ScriptableObject` and defines the same data you have in your `Skill` class. Using the `CreateAssetMenu` attribute for this class, you can make a new asset of this type. Right-click in your project window and navigate to the menu item `Combat/Skills/New Skill`, and then you will have an asset of this type.

Note: Because this is an asset, it implicitly has the property `name`, so you can name the `Skill` asset accordingly.

```C#
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "NewSkill.asset", menuName = "Combat/Skills/New Skill")]
public class Skill : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private int _damage = default;
    [SerializeField] private string _description = default;
    [SerializeField] private int _cooldown = default;

    public int damage => _damage;

    public string description => _description;

    public int cooldown => _cooldown;
}
```

Now that you can create `Skill` assets, go ahead and create your two skills and fill in the details in the inspector.

Next, you'll need a way to use the `Skill`. I've gotten rid of the `CoolDownManager` in favor of a button. Check out the following.

```C#
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class SkillButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Skill _skill = default;
    [SerializeField] private Button _button = default;
    [SerializeField] private Image _fillImage = default;

    private Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Hook up a method to listen for when the button is clicked.
        _button.onClick.AddListener(OnClick);
    }

    // This method is invoked when the button is clicked.
    private void OnClick()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CoolDownAnimation());
    }

    private IEnumerator CoolDownAnimation()
    {
        // Immediately keep the button from being clicked again.
        _button.interactable = false;
        _stopwatch.Start();

        while (_stopwatch.IsRunning && _stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < _skill.cooldown)
        {
            _fillImage.fillAmount = (float)_stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / _skill.cooldown;
            yield return null;
        }

        _fillImage.fillAmount = 0;
        _button.interactable = true;
        _stopwatch.Stop();
        _stopwatch.Reset();
    }

    // Use this to hook up references automatically.
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (_button == null)
        {
            _button = GetComponent<Button>();
        }

        if (_button != null && _fillImage == null)
        {
            _fillImage = _button.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
        }
    }
}
```

Attach the `SkillButton` component to the `Button` you wish to have controlling the skill, then hook up your various `Skill` objects to have them associated with that button.

With all of that out of the way, you should have functionality close to what you desire.